# Activate a List of URLs in Excel Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have 1700+ book title records in an Excel file.  Each of these 1700+ records has a cover image referenced, and those cover images are named by part of the title's ISBN# (such as 3-539-4.jpg).  All of these cover images need to be visually checked against their title records for a proper match.

What I've come up with as a process is to have the local URL in a column next to the title column.  Clicking each URL will open the image in my preview app so the cover image title can be verified as matching the title in the adjacent cell.  I have the local URLs in the column, but need a shortcut to making them all active, rather than setting each one individually in the Insert Hyperlink function (which would take approximately 1.5 forevers).

Is there a macro or VBA module i can use to make this happen over the whole column of URLs?

Below is an image of what I've started, showing the first one active.

[image: URL Activation Image]

Answer (score 1):

```
For each myCell in Range("A1:A1700")
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add myCell, Address:=MyCell.Value
Next myCell
```

Adjust for the actual range your links are in.

You should also be aware that there is no validation on the link, so a cell containing "Random Text" will link to "Random Text" whether or not that is a valid link

Comment: Thanks... this looks promising... if I could ask you help a bit further for this VBA novice, once I create this VBA module, how do I invoke?  I've saved it as "Set_URL()", but don't quite know what to do afterward.

Comment: in Excel: `Developer -> Code -> Macros` then pick it from the list

Comment: ok... just to be sure I'm in the right place, in my version on Mac the path is Tools > Macro > Macros, which brings a screen showing only one, which is, "'4_Correlate to BO Basic Fields.xlsm'!Module1.Set_URL"  (Set_URL is the name I gave it).  When I give  the run command, I get an error saying: 
"Compile error:
Invalid outside procedure".

I'm missing something, apparently.

Comment: You did put the code in a `Sub` and have an `End sub`? [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/invalid-outside-procedure) may prove useful

Comment: uhhh... nope... but tried a few cofigs on that and it's working, as:

"Sub Set_URL()
For Each myCell In Range("G2:G9")
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add myCell, Address:=myCell.Value
Next myCell
End Sub."

One thing, though, that's different from when I assign the URL in the Insert URL function:  Excel now requires permission to open each image when I use these links, whereas when I do it the other way, it doesn't.  Any known workaround for that?